# Limit of infinite product $ \lim_{x\to 1^-} \prod_{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}\right)^{x^n}$

Tags: limits, infinite-product

How do we calculate this limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to 1^-}  \prod_{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}\right)^{x^n}$$

I tried to take log and convert the resulting sum of logs into an integral but couldn't proceed after that. The answer is given as $\frac{2}{e}$ which probably means that taking log is the first step. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

This is given as the solution but I couldn't understand where step 3(they express the limit between two inequalities) comes from.

[image]

Comment: You can rewrite the product as $$\prod_{n=0}^{\infty } \left(\frac{1+x^{n+1}}{1+x^n}\right)^{x^n} =\frac12\left(1+x\right)^{1-x}\left(1+x^2\right)^{x(1-x)}\left(1+x^3\right)^{x^2(1-x)}...$$ I don't know if that will helpful, though.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I tried to simplify your expression, but it just seems too complicated.

Comment: The given solution doesn't make much sense. Maybe it can be salvaged, adding *a few* intermediate steps and correcting the obvious typo ($n-1$ instead of $x-1$), but there are simpler ways to prove the result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With $t_n=\ln(1+x^n)$, i.e. $x^n=e^{t_n}-1$, we have
$$\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^n\,(\ln(1+x^{n+1})-\ln(1+x^n))=-\sum^\infty_{n=0}(e^{t_n}-1)\,(t_n-t_{n+1}).$$ Since $t_0=\ln 2$ and $t_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, the sum on the RHS is an integral sum for $$\int^{\ln2}_0(e^t-1)\,dt$$ and since $0<t_n-t_{n+1}\le t_0-t_1=\ln2-\ln(1+x)\to0$ as $x\to1^{-}$,
$$\lim_{x\to1^{-}}\sum^\infty_{n=0}x^n\,(\ln(1+x^{n+1})-\ln(1+x^n))=-\int^{\ln2}_0(e^t-1)\,dt=\ln2-1.$$
EDIT: Here, we have an infinite integral sum, but this sum is the integral of a step function with value $e^{t_n}-1$ in $(t_{n+1}, t_n)$, and this function converges to $e^t-1$ monotonically, because of the monotony of $e^t-1$. So convergence is ensured in this case, too.

Comment: Nice approach. +1 I am not sure but the infinite Riemann sum approach works when the integrand is monotone.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh It does, I'll add a line of explanation, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I like this. Though this answer makes me wonder even more what magic the given solution is doing.

Comment: @Agile_Eagle I suspect the given solution is rather smart, but it glosses over a few crucial steps. I'm working on a reconstruction.

Comment: @ProfessorVector It would be great if you also decode the given solution. That would be a nice bonus